# How to check if a table exists in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, null

I'm trying to query on a table `dormpolicy`

```
String operatorName = "46001";
String selection = "(plmn = '"+operatorName+"')";
URI CONTENT_URI_DORMPOLICY = Uri.parse("content://nwkinfo/nwkinfo/dormpolicy");
cursor = phone.getContext.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI_DORMPOLICY, null,      selection, null, null);
```

I get error log:

```
 SQLiteQuery: exception: no such table: dormpolicy; 

 query: SELECT * FROM dormpolicy  WHERE ((plmn = '46001'))
```

This issue happen not always in my phone.

It seems that sometimes,when I access the table before the table was created.

Is there any way that before I query the table, I check if the table exist?

And how?

Answer (score 3):

My answer is twofold:

1. To strictly answer the question, I will redirect you to [How does one check if a table exists in an Android SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058909/how-does-one-check-if-a-table-exists-in-an-android-sqlite-database)
2. But rather than manually checking for tables' existence, I suggest you use the [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class. This will help you manage your tables in a structured way. That includes handling database upgrades. Have a look at this for a quick start: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db