# unable to send data to database, dont know whats wrong with the code

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

this code was working fine earlier and database have tables made back in 2017, but somehow these are not working any more, unable to create tables in database and retrieve data from it. Android studio throws no error.Stuck with this from last 1 week.

### Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private EditText inputName, inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName, inputLayoutEmail, inputLayoutPassword;
    private Button btnSignUp,btnLogout;
    //private static final String SITE_URL="http://182.19.41.106/src/okcl/";
    private static final String SITE_URL="http://www.wetswd.in/android-data";
    private static final String CHECK_URL    = SITE_URL+"sign-up.php";
    private static final String REGISTER_URL = SITE_URL+"android-process.php";
    private static final String UNREGISTER_URL = SITE_URL+"android-process_unregister.php";
    private static final String LOGOUT_URL   = SITE_URL+"sign-up.php;// logout.php";
    private static final String VERSION="1.05";
    private static final String pin   = "1234";//SN:added for flexibility
    private DBHelper mydb ;
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mydb = new DBHelper(this);
        //Add from XML Later
        //MyReceiver reMyreceive = new MyReceiver();
        //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("BROADCAST_ACTION");
        //registerReceiver(reMyreceive, filter);

        inputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_name);
        inputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_password);
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        Boolean isServiceRunning=isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class);
        if(isServiceRunning)
            btnSignUp.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        else btnSignUp.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        inputName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputName));
        inputPassword.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputPassword));
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                submitForm(view);
            }
        });
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //logOut();
                if (!validateName()) {
                    return;
                }
                if (!validatePassword()) {
                    return;
                }
                String macAdd = getMAC();
                String dateTime = getDateTime();
                String status = "out_"+inputName.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                        mydb.insertContact(macAdd , dateTime , "0", "0" , status , "N",pin);//inputName.getText().toString().trim(),
                        logOut(macAdd, inputName.getText().toString().trim(), inputPassword.getText().toString().trim(),pin);
                        //stopService();  is called inside logout
                    } else {
                        mydb.insertContact(macAdd , dateTime , "0", "0" , status.toUpperCase(), "N",pin);//,inputName.getText().toString().trim(),"9999"
                        btnLogout.setText(R.string.btn_LogOut);// "LOGOUT");
                        stopService(); //without Checking
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOG Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Validating form
     */
    private void submitForm(View view) {
        if (!validateName()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!validatePassword()) {
            return;
        }
        GPS_Slim gps = new GPS_Slim(MainActivity.this);
        //gps.setUsrId(inputName.getText().toString().trim());
        //gps.setPin(pin);
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            double latitude = 20.37;//Near Park;
            double longitude = 85.68;//Near Park
            double acc=9999.0;//gps.getAccuracy();
            String macAdd = getMAC();
            String dateTime = getDateTime();
            String status = "in_"+inputName.getText().toString().trim();
                if(isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())){
                    mydb.insertContact(macAdd , dateTime , String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude) , status , "N",pin);//,,String.valueOf(acc)
                    CheckUser(macAdd ,inputName.getText().toString().trim(),inputPassword.getText().toString().trim(),pin);
                }else {
                    mydb.insertContact(macAdd , dateTime , String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude) , status.toUpperCase(), "N",pin);//,inputName.getText().toString().trim(),String.valueOf(acc)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stored Internally", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    btnLogout.setText(R.string.btn_LogOut+" #"+inputName.getText().toString().trim());
                    startService(); //without Checking//SN:Can I pass Pin here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOG Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        //gps.locationManager.removeUpdates();//SN:Check if used?? GPS object is local here
        //gps = null;

    }
    private boolean validateName() {
        if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            inputLayoutName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
            requestFocus(inputName);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validatePassword() {
        if (inputPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            inputLayoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_password));
            requestFocus(inputPassword);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private View view;
        private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.input_name:      validateName(); break;
                case R.id.input_password:  validatePassword();  break;
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }
    private String getMAC(){
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        return  wInfo.getMacAddress();
    }
    private String getDateTime(){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return sdf.format(new Date());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    private void register(String mac, String dateT, String lat, String lon,String pin,String usr,String ver) {
        class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("macid",params[0]);
                data.put("datetime",params[1]);
                data.put("lat",params[2]);
                data.put("long",params[3]);
                data.put("pin",params[4]);//SN:added for Flexibility
                data.put("usr",params[5]);//SN:added for Flexibility
                data.put("ver",params[6]);//SN:added for Flexibility
                return ruc.sendPostRequest(REGISTER_URL,data);
            }
        }
        RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
        ru.execute(mac,dateT,lat,lon,pin,usr,ver);

    }
    private void CheckUser(String mac_id,final String user_id,String password,final String pin) {
        class CheckUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Received:"+s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Unauthorised User")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{ //Sucessfully Login
                    double latitude = 20.37;//Near Park;
                    double longitude = 85.68;//Near Park
                    String macAdd = getMAC();
                    String dateTime = getDateTime();
                    register(macAdd , dateTime , String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude),pin,user_id,VERSION);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startService();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOG Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    btnLogout.setText(btnLogout.getText().toString()+" *"+inputName.getText().toString().trim());
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("macid",params[0]);
                data.put("userid",params[1]);
                data.put("password",params[2]);
                data.put("pin",params[3]);
                return ruc.sendPostRequest(CHECK_URL,data);
            }
        }
        CheckUser ru = new CheckUser();
        ru.execute(mac_id,user_id,password,pin);
    }

    private void logOut(String mac_id,final String user_id,String password,final String pin) {
        class LogOUt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Received:"+s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Unauthorised User")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{ //Sucessfully Login
                    double latitude = 20.37;//Near Park;20.37 85.68
                    double longitude = 85.68;//Near Park
                    String macAdd = getMAC();
                    String dateTime = getDateTime();
                    register(macAdd , dateTime ,String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude),pin,user_id,VERSION);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Set Active=0 in android_data for macAdd
                    stopService();
                    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                    data.put("macid",macAdd);
                    data.put("pin",pin);//SN:added for Flexibility
                    String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(UNREGISTER_URL,data);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOG Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//20170821:Sn Testing
                    btnLogout.setText(R.string.btn_LogOut);//"LOGOUT");
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("macid",params[0]);
                data.put("userid",params[1]);
                data.put("password",params[2]);
                data.put("pin",params[3]);
                return ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGOUT_URL,data);
            }
        }
        LogOUt ru = new LogOUt();
        ru.execute(mac_id,user_id, password,pin);
    }
    private void doUpdate(String s) {
    }
    // Method to start the service
    public void startService() {Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);
        i.putExtra("user",inputName.getText().toString().trim());
        i.putExtra("SITE_URL",SITE_URL);
        i.putExtra("pin",pin);
        i.putExtra("mac",getMAC());
        i.putExtra("ver",VERSION);
        i.putExtra("REGISTER_URL",REGISTER_URL);
        startService(i);
        Intent iActivity=new Intent(getBaseContext(), logOut.class);
        iActivity.putExtra("user",inputName.getText().toString().trim());
        startActivity(iActivity);
    }
    // Method to start the service
    public void stopService() {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }
}
```

### DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "attendance.db";
    public static final String RECORD_TABLE_NAME = "Record";
    public static final String RECORD_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String RECORD_COLUMN_MACID = "macid";
    public static final String RECORD_COLUMN_DATETIME = "datetime";
    public static final String RECORD_COLUMN_LAT = "lat";
    public static final String RECORD_COLUMN_LONG = "long";
    private HashMap hp;
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Boolean tableExist=isTableExists("Record",false,db);//SN:Not Tested Code Added from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058909/how-does-one-check-if-a-table-exists-in-an-android-sqlite-database
        if(!tableExist) {
          db.execSQL("create table Record " +
            "(id integer primary key, macid text,datetime text,lat text, long text , status text , uploadstatus text, pin text)");
        }
        //TimeLog Added by SN to KeepTime of Last Update
        Boolean timeLogExist=isTableExists("timeLog",false,db);//SN:Not Tested Code Added from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058909/how-does-one-check-if-a-table-exists-in-an-android-sqlite-database
        if(!timeLogExist) {
            db.execSQL("create table timeLog " +  "(id integer primary key, macid text,datetime Long,comment text)");//??SN: Long
            //insertTimeLog(0L,"MSG_UPDATE","macid");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Record");
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS timeLog");
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insertContact (String macid, String datetime, String lat, String longi , String status, String uploadstatus,String pin) { //,String usr,String acc- removed
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        //macId,dateTime, String.valueOf(getLatitude()),String.valueOf(getLongitude()),"way","N",pin,usrId,accText
        contentValues.put("macid", macid);
        contentValues.put("datetime", datetime);
        contentValues.put("lat", lat);
        contentValues.put("long", longi);
        contentValues.put("status", status);
        contentValues.put("uploadstatus", uploadstatus);
        contentValues.put("pin", pin);
        db.insert("Record", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean updateContactNotUsed (Integer id, String macid, String datetime, String lat, String longi, String status, String uploadstatus) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("macid", macid);
        contentValues.put("datetime", datetime);
        contentValues.put("lat", lat);
        contentValues.put("long", longi);
        contentValues.put("status", status);
        contentValues.put("uploadstatus", uploadstatus);
        db.update("Record", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }
    public Cursor getData(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery( "select * from Record where id="+id+"", null );
    }
    public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, RECORD_TABLE_NAME);
    }

    public boolean updateTimeLog ( Long datetime,  String key) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("datetime", datetime);
        db.update("timeLog", contentValues, "comment = ? ", new String[] { key } );
        return true;
    }
    public boolean insertTimeLog ( Long datetime,  String key,String macid) { //,String usr,String acc- removed
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("datetime", datetime);
        contentValues.put("comment", key);
        contentValues.put("macid", macid);
        db.insert("timeLog", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }
    public Integer deleteContact (Integer id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("Record", "id = ? ",  new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<>();
        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from Record", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(!res.isAfterLast()){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(RECORD_TABLE_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        res.close();
        return array_list;
    }
    public boolean isTableExists(String tableName, boolean openDb,SQLiteDatabase mDatabase) {
        if(openDb) {
            if(mDatabase == null || !mDatabase.isOpen()) {
                mDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
            }
            if(!mDatabase.isReadOnly()) {
                mDatabase.close();
                mDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
            }
        }
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
        if(cursor!=null) {
            if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                cursor.close();
                return true;
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

logcat-https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J1vhdRpP0GOQaRoCycHXWkXi_HiKPxxE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: any error log !!!!!!!

Comment: no error in logcat

Comment: are you sure ???? is it storing data in db ?

Comment: http://www.wetswd.in/android-data/

Comment: this is thesite url,i get all the toasts right but it doesnt get stored in databse

Comment: 04-16 12:15:46.287 27364-27377/? E/zygote: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe

Comment: got this error after changing the url.

Comment: ok, please update your question with error log,

Comment: this is my logcat https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J1vhdRpP0GOQaRoCycHXWkXi_HiKPxxE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your database version to 2, as your are adding new tables to your database you need to upgrade database version.

```
 public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 2);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, tried that but problem still persists